# Calculate start time given end time (datetime2) and duration (time(7))

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FinalDateTime Datetime2(7), 
 ElapsedTime Time(7))

INSERT INTO @TABLE (FinalDateTime, ElapsedTime)
SELECT '2014-01-21 00:00:00.1110010','12:00:00.1100009' 
  -- Expected Output = '2014-01-20 12:00:00.0010001'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-01-20 14:00:00.1110010','02:00:00.1100009' 
  -- Expected Output = '2014-01-20 12:00:00.0010001'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-01-20 12:02:00.1110010','00:02:00.1100009' 
  -- Expected Output = '2014-01-20 12:00:00.0010001'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-01-20 12:00:02.1110010','00:00:02.1100009' 
  -- Expected Output = '2014-01-20 12:00:00.0010001'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2014-01-20 12:00:00.1110010','00:00:00.1100009' 
  -- Expected Output = '2014-01-20 12:00:00.0010001'

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

I want to subtract `time(7)` from `Datetime2(7)`. I can't figure out how to subtract the whole time instead of HH/MM/SS/MS separately.

Comment: Have you tried to CAST() or CONVERT() one of the two objects and then run your logic?

Comment: Yep, CAST/Convert will convert time to datetime with yyyy-mm-dd part as 1900-01-01 and that doesn't seem to help me as diff would be HUGE (byte size wise) and you will get overflow error. :(

Comment: I have DateTime2(7) value and time(7) value. I need to subtract time from datetime and get DateTime2(7) value. i.e. A process ended on 2014-01-20 12:00:00.0000001. the process ran for 03:02:01.000005. I need to find the process start "datetimestamp"

Comment: And is granularity to the nanosecond really important? Why wouldn't you store the end time instead of the duration?

Comment: I guess millisecond granularity is OK. I have to find a way to work with these two columns and their datatypes to find starttime (output). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the granularity, you need to perform the nanosecond calculation separately. So, subtract the elapsed time in whole seconds, then subtract the nanosecond part.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (FinalDateTime Datetime2(7), ElapsedTime Time(7));

INSERT INTO @TABLE (FinalDateTime, ElapsedTime) VALUES
('2014-01-21 00:00:00.1110010','12:00:00.1100009'),
('2014-01-20 14:00:00.1110010','02:00:00.1100009'),
('2014-01-20 12:02:00.1110010','00:02:00.1100009'),
('2014-01-20 12:00:02.1110010','00:00:02.1100009'),
('2014-01-20 12:00:00.1110010','00:00:00.1100009');

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    FinalDateTime, 
    ElapsedTime,
    ElapsedSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00', ElapsedTime),
    AdditionalNanoseconds = DATEPART(NANOSECOND, ElapsedTime)
  FROM @TABLE
)
SELECT 
  FinalDateTime, 
  ElapsedTime, 
  StartTime = DATEADD(NANOSECOND, -AdditionalNanoseconds, 
    DATEADD(SECOND, -ElapsedSeconds, FinalDateTime)
  ) 
FROM x;
```

You can do this more concisely, of course, I just feel like the CTE helps express the steps.

```
SELECT 
  FinalDateTime, 
  ElapsedTime, 
  StartTime = DATEADD(NANOSECOND, -(DATEPART(NANOSECOND, ElapsedTime)), 
    DATEADD(SECOND, -(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00', ElapsedTime)), FinalDateTime)
  ) 
FROM @TABLE;
```

Comment: This is a REALLY nice logic you used here to tackle this challange. Much much appreciated. I need to get a better handle on these date/time queries..ok bye!